# Change global variable whenever the function called

Tags: python, variables, global

Could someone please explain to me how could I change the value of x to "didn't work" whenever the globallyChange() function is called? Thank you very much!

```
def globallyChange():
    x = "didn't work"

def main():
    global x
    x = 10
    globallyChange() #Call the function for changes.
    print(x)

main()

CURRENT OUTPUT: >> 10
```

I have tried the same thing with list/array being the global variable, and when the globallyChange() function is called, it actually DID change the global variable list. I was wondering how it is different between an integer/string/bool global variable and list global variable?

```
def globallyChange():
    lst.append(1)
    lst.append(5)
    lst.append(7)

def main():
    global lst
    lst = []
    globallyChange() #Call the function for changes.
    print(lst)

main()

OUTPUT: >> [1,5,7]
```

Comment: Assignment always defaults to local names, merely referencing will try the local namespace, then the global one.

Comment: The second version isn't assigning the variable, it's modifying the list.

Comment: Just declare `global x` at the start of `globallyChange`. If you don't, as you assign it a new value, Python will consider it local to this function.

Comment: " I was wondering how it is different between an integer/string/bool global variable and list global variable?" **there is no difference**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a `global` declaration in all functions that assign to the variable. So it should be:

```
def globallyChange():
    global x
    x = "didn't work"
```

The reason you don't need this in the version with the list is that you're not assigning to the variable. You're just reading the variable; which automatically looks for a global variable if no local variable can be found. `append()` doesn't assign to the variable, it modifies the list in place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define x as a global variable in all functions that refer to it. Otherwise python creates a new local variable.

Try this:

```
x = 0
def globallyChange():
    global x
    x = "didn't work"

def main():
    global x
    x = 10
    globallyChange() #Call the function for changes.
    print(x)
```